# How can I set my values with the Scale widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, trackbar

I have this function and with this function I want to change my 2 last values from adaptive threshold 11 and 15 with a `Scale` widget. I want to use the `Scale` from tkinter. I already have the function for the slider but I don't know how to connect it to my image editing function.

```py
from tkinter import *
import cv2

def button_action():
    img = cv2.imread("img.jpg")

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    edges = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 15)

    cv2.imshow("cartoon", edges)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    def show_values():
    print (w1.get(), w2.get())

master = Tk()
w1 = Scale(master, from_=0, to=42)
w1.set(19)
w1.pack()
w2 = Scale(master, from_=0, to=200, orient=HORIZONTAL)
w2.set(23)
w2.pack()

change_button5 = Button(master, text="gray", command=button_action)
change_button5.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: no one can help me? sorry for my english

Comment: Tkinter doesn't have anything called a "trackbar", and neither does your code. Are you asking about the `Scale` widget?

Comment: yes about the scale widget. I use it in my code but i cant edit my picture with this function. why?